# multiple onchange submit from a while in php not working

Tags: php, html

I have a table in HTML that gets built from a WHILE ()  {  }

inside this table, I have a drop down menu and on select, I have the onchange= command to execute a part of PHP code above on same file.  Everything works well, except when I have multiple result in my while because I can't distinguish each form ... how can I do this.

I have a hidden value.  but how do I manage this from the  if (isset($_POST['status'])) stand point ?

SAMPLE CODE

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['status'])) 
{   }

?>
```

HTML HERE

```
<?php

while ($bookingrequest2 = mysql_fetch_array( $bookingrequest )) 
{

        echo "<tr><td>
            <form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\" name=\"reply\">
            <select name=\"status\" class=\"form-field\" onchange=\"reply.submit();\" >
            <option selected value=\"0\">Make a Selection</option>
            <option value=\"Approve\">Approve</option>
            <option value=\"1\">Modify</option>
            <option value=\"Decline\">Decline</option>
            </select>
         <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$bookingrequest2['booking_id']."\" name=\"booking_id\"/>

                          </form></td></tr>";

}


?>
```

Comment: Add a hidden field to the form that contains something that distinguishes it.

Comment: ok, say I add a hidden field with a variable $var ++ so the var changes each time.. how does the if(isset($_POST...)  gets to know which of the form was submitted ?

Comment: Read the value of `$_POST['hidden']` to get it.

Comment: but how to I write the PHP to read an unlimited amount of results... 
I may have 20 forms with a different hidden value... I can't write the same PHP coded 20 times and write if(isset($_POST['hidden1']) ... $_POST['hidden2'] ....

Comment: No, it's just `$_POST['hidden']`, and its value will be `1`, `2`, etc.

Comment: I updated the question. I already had a hidden value... so now I have 2.  1 that takes the info from the while and the other from the incremental variable... but I still don't get how to handle the $_POST[ ]

Comment: Please don't change your question like that. Now my answer makes no sense, since it just says to do what you're already doing.

Comment: You don't need two hidden values. The original one should be all you need. I don't understand the problem now.

Comment: sorry about modifying the question, the problem is if I have several results in my while, nothing happens when I make a dropdown selection. It only works when there is only 1 result in the while

Comment: Change `reply.submit()` to `this.form.submit()`. When there are multiple forms with the same name, the `window.<formname>` is an array, not a single form, so you can't just call `<formname>.submit()`.

Comment: AAHHH.,,.. it works.. that was my issue.. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add a hidden input field that identifies the database row. And change `reply.submit()` to `this.form.submit()`, because you can't refer to `reply` as a single element when there are multiple forms with the same name.

```
while ($bookingrequest2 = mysql_fetch_array( $bookingrequest )) 
{

        echo "<tr><td>
            <form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\" name=\"reply\">
            <select name=\"status\" class=\"form-field\" onchange=\"this.form.submit();\" >
            <option selected value=\"0\">Make a Selection</option>
            <option value=\"Approve\">Approve</option>
            <option value=\"1\">Modify</option>
            <option value=\"Decline\">Decline</option>
            </select>       
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$bookingrequest2['id']}'>
            </form></td></tr>";
}
```

Then the form processing code can do:

```
$booking_id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: I did that, but It only works when the while has 1 result. As soon as I have 2 results, the dropdown menu selection doesn't work.

Comment: I just answered that in the comments to the question.